# Steps involved to change connection string in Entity Framework code-first approach for ASP.NET Web API

Tags: azure, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, ef-code-first

We have an existing ASP.NET Web API which uses a code-first approach with Entity Framework pointing to am on-premise SQL Server. We were managing using `DbContext`.

We migrated the database from on-premise SQL Server to Azure SQL. Now the requirement is to point existing Web API application to Azure SQL to the same database. It is not working if we directly change the connection string in the `web.config`.

Could you please let us know the steps involved?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your **.csproj** details

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way i acheived Connecting Application to Azure SQL by changing in **web.config**  and **DBContext**

1 - Check your connection string with **Providername** included

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDbConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:******.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=entity;Encrypt=True;
         TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=Active Directory Default;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

2 - provide your  connection string **name**  in  your DBContext

```
public MyDatabaseContext() : base("name=MyDbConnection")
{
}
```

3  - Run Solution
**Result**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was getting "Invalid value for key 'authentication' " error when i use Authentication=Active Directory Default in connection string, Any idea ?                      
But it worked when i used  Authentication=Active Directory Integrated in the conn string.

Comment: Authentication=Active Directory Integrated  specifies that the application should use Windows Integrated Authentication to connect to the database.
please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16)